# remove javascript warning of arrow function

Tags: javascript

i have this function

```
const currentClaims = claimOpenList.filter(c => {

  if (`${c.claimid}` === claimid || (claimid !== undefined && c.claimid_ === claimid)) {
    console.log('claimOpenList > Se encontro claimid: ', claimid)
    return c
  }else {null}
})
```

It works and does what it is suppoused to do, but I want to get rid of this warning:

> Expected to return a value at the end of arrow function
>   array-callback-return

It says the problem is on the line

```
  const currentClaims = claimOpenList.filter(c => {
```

Comment: `else { return null; }`

Comment: You don't need an *else* block, you can end with `return null`.

Comment: Again, you're using filter again, and returning `c`. You should simply return true or false for filter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should return something like below in the method

```js
const currentClaims = claimOpenList.filter(c => {

  if (`${c.claimid}` === claimid || (claimid !== undefined && c.claimid_ === claimid)) {
    console.log('claimOpenList > Se encontro claimid: ', claimid)
    return c
  }
  return false;
})
```

Answer (score 0):

All cases needs to return some value.

```
...
else {return null}
```

Or just add return at the end of your function

```
...
return null;
```